# codeigniter can't find where route is defined

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a really strange situation. I am taking over someone else's code. The framework is CodeIgniter (php). There's a route that is working and it's not defined in the route config file, so I can't figure out how it can be working. Is there another place you can suggest to look for where a route could be defined? I did a find over the whole project but no luck. Thank you.

Comment: please look at app/config/routes.php.

Comment: Thanks Akhil. I checked there first, but it't not defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that with CodeIgniter, you don't necessarily have to set up an explicit route. A controller becomes a route. The route takes on the file name. So if you have a controller dashboard.php with an index method, you will automatically have a route http://yoursite.com/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Routes can be defined in two places:

1) .htaccess file

2) In a controller a method named `_remap()`

e.g.

```
public function _remap($method) {
    if ($method == 'some_method') {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

Please check these two places, you might find where the URL is rewritten.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I did check the .htaccess files, but I'll look for the _remap.

Comment: Hey, .htaccess is different. In this file URL rewrites are done. Please check your controllers.

Comment: Did a search through the project for _remap and didn't find. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: _remap() function is not a .htacces code, please look for it in controllers.

Comment: I searched the whole project, including controllers.

Answer (score 0):

you must check htaccess again. You can also check root's index file as there is an option to set custom routing in index also.